# What is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \sum_\limits{n=1}^{x} \frac {1}{n^n}$?

Tags: limits

Fun problem. Can't seem to find an exact solution. The approximate value I'm getting is 1.29

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\lim$ using `\lim`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed-form expression for this series, but it's quite famous and is known via "Sophomore's dream"

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622920/infinite-sum-of-1-nn) which does not have an answer.